# What do hats get me after winter bash is over?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2012

> the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th

Do the hats affect me in any way after the 4th? A badge or something in my profile about how many I unlocked?

**Edit:** Can I request some form of persistence... please?

Comment: We totally need a Mad Hatter badge.

Comment: That's my birthday. I guess I shouldn't participate if I am to avoid having a meltdown on my birthday.

Comment: Ewww, I dont want to imagine a unicorn being born .. sounds pokey

Comment: I really hope the horn is an after-delivery installation...

Comment: You can keep them indefinitely, but you'll need 1) A color printer, 2) some good cardstock and duct tape, and 3) to not have a contact allergy to duct tape.

Comment: You should ship hats I feel

Comment: We wanna keep our hats forever !!

Comment: @Monica: how many horned animals are born with their horns? They grow later. It's different with unicorns, though, they are born as ponies. It's the pink fairy who turns good ponies into unicorns.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Do the hats affect me in any way after the 4th? A badge or something in my profile about how many I unlocked?

Well, only if you choose to put such information in your profile. More realistically, you get the sense of pride that you unlocked X many hats on Y many sites, and that you got to have a little fun on, [of all sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), Stack Overflow.

It's fun! Have fun with it! If it lasted all the time, this wouldn't be nearly as special as it is. Besides, never fear -- we might even do this next year!

Comment: But I need something about it to last. Such as the number of hats I have or a badge... NEED.

Comment: @AustinHenley TAKE SCREENCAPTURES. Screengrabs are forever. Well, no. Screengrabs are until Photoshop, but still!

Comment: I'm thinking yearly tradition. Shenanigans this time of year are unavoidable, this promo (even early on) has proven to be a very constructive venue for that energy.

Comment: @Aarthi Screencaptures are not good enough if you are one of the people who need to make a competition out of everything, because they won't be able to beat me (http://imgh.us.nyud.net/hatparty.png) :3 I don't care about it that much, but I understand the problem. I think making a contest out of everything spoils the fun, but for many people it works the opposite way!

Answer (score 14):

In all likelihood, nothing, except maybe fond memories. The [Winter Bash FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq) has this to say:

> After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, **not a permanent addition** to the site.

Also, when we had the Hat Dash event at Arqade last year, we didn't get to keep anything either. Unlocked hats were displayed publicly on [hatdash.com](http://hatdash.com/) for a while, but eventually that was taken down and consigned to the promos archive.

Comment: I *need* persistence!

Comment: Yeah well. We were [promised persistence](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3593/what-should-happen-at-the-end-of-hat-dash/3595#3595) of a sort and that didn't happen either. It's injustice I say

Comment: I worked hard for those... uh... however many hats I got on Gaming. Hard, I tell you!

Comment: @lunboks: I'm very disappointed that a hat event on *gaming* was not preserved in the form of a high-score table, with people allowed to enter their initials. I mean, come on.

Comment: Stackexchange should ship it :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to roll your own memories.  Which you can do, and accumulate, from year to year, like [this user](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/4794/y-e-z) has:

[image: profile pic]

From that user's "about" text:

> That is a Discraft Ultrastar 175g disc (a frisbee) (now wearing a football helmet from WinterBash 2014, a head of hair from WinterBash 2015, some kind of trophy thing from WinerBash 2016, and a baseball cap from WinterBash 2017).

Originally the user used that frisbee as the profile pic.  Then there was a WinterBash and it gained a football helmet.  And then it kept going.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I request some form of persistence... please?"

Take a screen-shot of your hat-wearing avatar.

Save the screen-shot as an image file.

Use GIMP to create a new avatar icon from the screen-shot image; Then use it year-round.