# What is Winter Bash all about?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

I would like to know what winter hats are all about.

Do they add any reputation or badges later?

I'm excited about these winter hats.

Comment: Read the [FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq)

Comment: Also check out [Welcome to Winter Bash 2012!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/) on the company blog. :)

Comment: Why the down-votes? I've seen too much discussion on winter hats, and the answer below is the first explanation i've seen. BTW, i think they're a stupid idea!

Comment: These winterba.sh links are now dead ends.

Comment: It should be noted that this is a long standing annual tradition on the Stack Exchange sites.  Anybody remember when it first started?  Was 2012 the first year?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Winter Bash FAQ](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/faq)

> #### What happens after January 5th?
>
> After January 5th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

Comment: It is worth noting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159171/169404