# How long will hats be in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Winter Bash all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159187/what-is-winter-bash-all-about)

Are hats just a temporary winter feature or they will be kept for the rest of the year?

Comment: Somewhat related: [What do hats get me after January 4th?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159171/169404)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Winterba.sh FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq):

> **What happens after January 4th?**
>
> After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear.
>   This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent
>   addition to the site.

Comment: I should read it. <facepalm>

Comment: [Exact duplicate answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159190/187824) :)

Comment: :( that's no fun

Answer (score 1):

Hats will last until **4 January 2013** after which point they will disappear.