# Summary of Winter Bash

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Winter Bash all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159187/what-is-winter-bash-all-about)

Winter Bash seems to have really taken off here and I am a newer user. Can anyone summarize everything that has been discussed over the past few days on here?

The http://winterba.sh/faq is lacking considering all the questions under the `winterbash` tag.

Comment: [Welcome to Winter Bash 2012](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/)

Comment: This is a dup of everything. That's got to be some kind of record.

Answer (score 16):

**Do Things.  Get Hats.**

Ends January 4th.

Answer (score 7):

[winterbash](/questions/tagged/winterbash) is the only link you need.

There is no need to add that to the FAQ.

Comment: I want half the rep you got from this answer for creating the tag.

Comment: @Yannis eh? wadya mean?

Comment: Your answer is based on the [winterbash] tag, a tag [I created](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=162704). You owe me half the rep you got here... (I'm trolling you Neal ;).

Comment: @Yannis lol lucky.

Answer (score 2):

Summary:

- Do good things on site
- Get hats
- Show hat to others
- Have fun
- Hate having fun.

Comment: There is no fun on SE... you know that....

Comment: Only a few days in the year. So enjoy.

Comment: @aman You can _have_ fun, you are just required to _hate_ it at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a list of all the hats and how to get them [here](http://winterba.sh/).

From that Q/A:

> **Why are you doing this to us?**
>
> For sites that have hats on by default, your moderator teams or your
>   communities indicated that hats would be a fun, lighthearted thing to
>   do. Why did we offer it? Because we thought it was a nice way to
>   finish out a really amazing year. You can always decide you hate hats
>   and turn them off.

Comment: but who the hell hates hats?

Answer (score 0):

**Just have fun!** don't let it ruin you like everyone else.