# Objective : Hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Winter Bash all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159187/what-is-winter-bash-all-about)
>   [Summary of Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159722/summary-of-winter-bash)

What is the objective behind "hats" ? I mean, apart from celebrating, will it reflect in your profile even after the winter bash ? (i. e. 4th Jan 13) ?
your thoughts ?

Comment: However one can make several screenshots of own gravatar with different hats and save them for the future use throughout the year 2013.

Comment: Just for fun...

Comment: See [What do hats get me after January 4th?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159171/169404)

Comment: Hats justify themselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Winter Bash website](http://winterba.sh/)

> "Stack Exchange invites you to celebrate the end of a great year ...with HATS! As you use your site, you'll discover hats and other items **hidden behind certain actions**. Collect all of them, some of them, or none of them, but be quick – **the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th!**"

Emphasis mine.

So most likely the idea behind them (besides fun) is to promote certain actions. A concept fairly similar to the usual badges, just a bit more seasonal/playful.

And no, after January 4th 2013 they will no longer remain. It will be a sad day for hats.

Comment: Your current avatar+hat composition is awesome.

Comment: @Chichiray I like the whole "Clockwork Orange" feel of it...I might just keep it. :)

Comment: Also change your name to *Ludwig Van*, and nobody will dare to post snarky comments under your questions, just in case :)