# Do large events (e.g. Christmas) have an impact on user activity within Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, users, activity

For example, large celebrations such as Christmas Day or New Years' Day - I *imagine* people would be more inclined to spend some time offline during events like these.

**Are there noticeable changes in the number of questions/answers which are posted on Stack Exchange, during large events?**

Comment: Isn't it a bit early to start talking about [HATS!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270508/is-there-a-simple-page-what-is-winter-bash-and-whats-all-this-about-hats-c) ... ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are.

But you don't need me to tell you this; the data is public:

```
declare @LastDay as DateTime = (select max(CreationDate) from Posts);

select cast(CreationDate as Date) d, count(*)
from PostsWithDeleted
where cast(CreationDate as Date) < cast(@LastDay as Date)
group by cast(CreationDate as Date)
order by cast(CreationDate as Date)
```

[image: number of posts by day for Stack Overflow]

Behold, the clearly-visible dips every Christmas + New Years.

You can even observe [variations in activity within the week](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/711543#graph):

[image: posts by week day for Stack Overflow]

Contrast the activity above (on Stack Overflow) with [the pattern on Mi Yodeya](https://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/711544#graph)

[image: posts by week day for Mi Yodeya]

Answer (score 7):

Shog9's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299849/162102) shows data for SO and [this query with similar results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/711550#graph) shows network-wide activity (h/t rene).  On a site-by-site basis you can see some variations.  This past December, MSE actually had an *increase* around that time (though December 24 and 25, which were a Saturday and Sunday, had a local dip that's a little bigger than MSE's usual weekend dips):

[image: MSE traffic]

Posts actually increased some, maybe because of Winterbash:

[image: MSE posts]

The Workplace, on the other hand, had a slump for a week.  Gee, do you think people post about the workplace *from* the workplace? :-)

[image: Workplace traffic]

Mi Yodeya, where the almost-entirely-Jewish inhabitants don't care about Christmas, saw "business as usual":

[image: Mi Yodeya traffic]

So there's some variation, though the overall trend, as Shog9 showed, is for dips in activity.

Comment: No, Shog9's first graph is SO, [this is the Networkwide query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/711550#graph)  and [this without StackOverflow's dominance (and it's meta)](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/711556#graph)

Comment: @rene thanks; I didn't see any indication (or query link) in the answer and judged from axis values, always an iffy proposition.  I've updated.

Comment: Heh... The entire code listing is a link...

Comment: Oh, clever @Shog.  Code styling overrides link styling and I didn't happen to pass the mouse over the code directly, so I didn't notice.