# Points from earning hats in the winter bash?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I am very enthusiastic about earning hats on multiple sites in the winter bash. It is an engaging concept too. However, I am wondering if my reputation can increase because of that i.e. get more points.

Answer (score 5):

Hats themselves do not give any reputation points.

However, if you make a post or suggest an edit to get a hat, and your post gets upvoted or your edit gets accepted, you get the reputation from that.

Answer (score 2):

Hats are temporarily, as explained also in [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash):

> ... that typically runs from mid-December until early January each year ...

Also, as mentioned in [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270511/286501) to ' [Is there a simple page, "What is Winter Bash, and what's all this about hats"? Can we have one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270508/286501) ':

> When the event is over, the "hats" are all gone and can't be accessed anymore.

So as soon the hats disappear again, all *points* (= reputation) gained from earning hats would have to be deducted also again ... assuming that such reputation changes would be consistent with what happens if questions or answers disappear (= get deleted), in which case the reputation changes from deleted posts get corrected also.

Answer (score -1):

Increasing the number of hats does not increase the reputation. [To increase reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) check that and Votes on posts cause you to gain (or sometimes lose) reputation.