# Badge for Winter Bash participants

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, winter-bash

Okay, here's another idea for those who like Winter Bash.

For those who participated in Winter Bash (got a hat) give a one-time badge.

**You could give a Silver badge to anyone who participated**, or

- Bronze - Up to 5 hats
- Silver - Up to 15 hats
- Gold - More than 15 hats

There is already a precedent of the `Beta` Badge, for those who participated in the private Beta of a site (I got into SO in the public Beta and missed out on that one).

Comment: I'd say gold should be more like twenty or twenty-five hats -- really requiring some work. I personally hit fourteen just hanging around Meta, doing my normal thing, for a few hours on the day WB started.

Comment: My suggestion for thresholds: bronze = 1 hat, silver = 15 hats, gold = _all_ the hats, including the secret ones (except maybe [the punyon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard)).

Comment: Related: [What do hats get me after January 4th?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159171/169404)

Comment: I like the idea but not 3 badges. It should just be one bronze badge just like the Precognitive badge.

Comment: Which reminds me @JoshCaswell thanks for correcting my Latin on that one answer :P

Comment: It's impossible to get exactly 15 hats. Once you get the 15th, you earn [Gotta catch 'em all](http://winterba.sh/gotta-catch-em-all) for it.

Comment: You're implying that editing others' Latin is abnormal, @Aarthi? That would certainly be a sad state of affairs. :p

Comment: @bfavaretto: So "exactly fifteen"
 would be the gold badge then, huh?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Eh? No no, I'm genuinely thanking you! :)

Comment: @Aarthi: Well, you're certainly welcome.

Answer (score 11):

No, I don't think we should.

This whole hat thing (in my opinion), already generated enough buzz and noise, even without these badges.

I've already seen people opening gigantic debates on whether it's okay or not to ask for upvotes in chat and whatnot. So no, I don't think we actually should be giving *yet another* tag for someone so localized.

Comment: Is the badge really going to generate noise? Everything is going to die down once the Winter Bash is over.

Comment: @Dynamic: That's one of the points. The event is so local, so decorative, and so insignificant, I see no need for a badge. Badges are awarded for positive actions on the site. Hats are the same with a twist, you can wear them on your avatar. You don't award a badge for getting a lot of badges, now do you?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It is *not* insignificant.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Also comparing hats and badges is like apples and oranges. Awarding a badge for hats is fine since hats are temporary and different.

Answer (score 6):

**I completely agree with this idea, but maybe it should be one participation badge.**

Possible badge name could be **milliner**. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatmaking), a milliner:

> designs, makes, trims, or sells hats

We didn't make them, but I like the word!

Another idea from the comments is **The Mad Hatter**.

Comment: The **mad hatter** ? :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Yes, please. Pretty please!

Comment: "Mad Hatter" is a very
 good choice, but also the obvious choice. I like the slightly esoteric spin provided by "Milliner".

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to my question, [What do hats get me after January 4th?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159171/169404)

I like the idea of giving users a badge for participating in this event. However, 3 badges is too much focus on something so unrelated and temporary.

A single bronze badge just like Precognitive would work great.