# Do we lose our hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do hats get me after January 4th?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159171/what-do-hats-get-me-after-january-4th)

On the [Winter Bash page](http://winterba.sh/) it says
"but be quick – the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th!".
Does this mean that we cannot collect any more hats after January 4th or that all of the hats, even the ones I have gotten, will disappear?

Comment: That's what I got out of it. Good thing I only have a pair of glasses and no hats :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, after the 4th of January it'll all be gone.

From the [FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq):

> #### What happens after January 4th?
>
> After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

The hats will all disappear. Enjoy them now, while they are here! *Carpe Petasus!*

Comment: What? I will not longer be a chef? Must cook now, to last all year, before those mad cooking skills disappear!

Comment: You can always download your hat-wearing avatar and re-upload it..  At least then you can keep *one* hat!

Comment: @MikeChristensen: The hats extend beyond the avatar image. I'd be wearing a truncated hat.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - Wish I could. It's the wrong aspect ratio :(

Comment: Hmm, well then I guess that was a bad idea then!

Comment: @Oded - Your hat actually fits pretty well, so you could take a screenshot and try to manipulate the image a bit and re-upload to Gravatar :)  Or you could [grab it out of the sprite image](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/sprite-32.png) and try to add it in yourself.