# How long could I keep my hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do hats get me after January 4th?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159171/what-do-hats-get-me-after-january-4th)

I love my hat! How long could I keep it? Is it a permanent system (which I want)?

I had thought that I could save my image with the hat and set as a whole image, but the hat exceeds the bounds.

Comment: The hats will all disappear. Enjoy them now, while they are here! Carpe Petasus!

Comment: January 4th is the hataclysm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq)

> #### What happens after January 4th?
>
> After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, **not a permanent addition to the site**.

Comment: But I do love my hat! well, c'est la vie.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can always have it in your About section:

> [image]

:-D

Comment: Thank you! I will come here to see my hat whenever I miss it!

Comment: A perfect fit. :D

Comment: @irrelephant Yes, that's why I love it. It fits me originally.

Comment: @Skyler good chance all questions regarding winter bash will be swiped clean when it's all over so better copy that image to your machine.. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh, thanks for notice!